# Magento swatches not loading in home page latest and featured products section

Tags: magento, configurable-product

In my magento home page, latest products & featured products section's color swatches of products is not working. I tried with following code in home page Custom Layout Update XML but it did not work:

```
<reference name="content">
   <block type="catalog/product_new" name="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml">
    <block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.name.after" as="name.after" />
    <block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.after" as="after" />
<block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.options.configurable.renderers" as="attr_renderers" />
   </block>

</reference>

 <PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable translate="label" module="catalog">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Configurable)</label>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.configurable" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.configurable.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                    <label>Product Extra Info</label>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.availability" as="product_type_availability" template="catalog/product/view/type/availability/default.phtml" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable" as="options_configurable" before="-" template="catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.options.configurable.renderers" as="attr_renderers" />
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.options.configurable.after" as="after" />
            </block>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
```

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for configurable products:

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list-no-toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.name.after" as="name.after" />
                    <block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.after" as="after" />
<action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>3</category_id></action>
<action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
<action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>desc</dir></action>
</block>
</reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/configurableswatches/product-media.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/configurableswatches/swatches-list.js</name></action>
        </reference> 
       <reference name="product_list.name.after">
            <block type="core/template" name="product_list.swatches" template="configurableswatches/catalog/product/list/swatches.phtml" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="product_list.after">
            <block type="configurableswatches/catalog_media_js_list" name="configurableswatches.media.js.list" />
        </reference>
```

Comment: list-no-toolbar.phtml  is a modification of list.phtml without toolbar.